# Horspool algorithm for multiple occurrences of the same pattern

Tags: c++, string

I've implemented in C++ the Horspool algorithm (depending on the *Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algorithms* by *Anany Levitin*, 2nd edition, p. 258) for finding the position of the first occurrence of a desired pattern in the text. However, I want to extend the algorithm to find multiple occurrences of the same pattern. Unfortunately, I got stuck on the latter implementation. You can see my code below:

The function calculates and returns the position of the first occurrence of a desired pattern in the text. The shift sizes are stored in the ShiftTable and the ShiftTable is indexed by the characters of a desired alphabet. Additionally, the integer *counter* is used for counting the total comparisons between pattern's and text's characters. The counter initially has a zero value. How could I extend this to find multiple occurences of the same pattern?

I attempted the following in the body of the main() function but it's NOT EFFICIENT although it works. If the first occurrence of the pattern is encountered, its position will be printed and the part of the text which ends with the first occurrence of the pattern will be erased. Moreover, the programme will check the remaining text for the pattern and so on.

```
int counter=0;
while ((position = Find(pattern,text,ShiftTable,counter)) != -1) {
    cout << position << endl;
    text = text.erase(0,result+m);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you always start at the beginning (`i = m - 1`). If you want to resume a previous search, just pass in the last position to start from.

In the following I’ve removed the `counter` variable – what’s the use of that anyway?

```
int Find(string pattern, string text, int *ShiftTable, int start = 0)
```

… and …

```
i = start + m - 1,
```

… and just call the code as follows:

```
while ((position = Find(pattern,text,ShiftTable,position)) != -1)  {
    cout << position << endl;
    ++position;
}
```

Comment: "I’ve removed the counter variable – what’s the use of that anyway?" Guess: comparing real examples to theoretical worst-case. That's what I'd use it for.

Comment: Konrad Rudolph: Many thanks for your help! It is working very well now. :-)

Daniel Fischer: Yes, I know it may seem trivial but it has to be a part of my programme in order to record some statistical results.

Comment: @Stavros You misunderstood. The first part of my comment was a quote from Konrad's answer. I guessed what you're using `counter` for - correctly, it seems :). I often use counters for that purpose too.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I completely misunderstood. :-)

Comment: @Daniel Seems obvious now. Yes.